# Couchbase N1QL sub-select combined with GROUP BY

Tags: subquery, grouping, couchbase, sql++

I have the following flight offer data structure given:

```
{
  "offerIdentifier": "123",
  "flyFrom": "HAM",
  "flyTo": "LGW",
  "provider": "LH",
  "price": 207,
  "bookingUrl": "https://example.com/",
  "flightCombinationIdentifier": "HAM-LGW-201791570-20179171835"
}
```

The `flightCombinationIdentifier` property's value can an will appear on multiple offers.

Now I would like to group by `flightCombinationIdentifier` and find the lowest price available for this combination which should ideally result in a structure like this:

```
{
  "offerIdentifier": "456",
  "flightCombinationIdentifier": "HAM-LGW-201791570-20179171835",
  "offer": [
    {
      "bookingUrl": "http://example.com/",
      "price": 97,
      "provider": "LH"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I came up with the following N1QL query:

```
select b.flightCombinationIdentifier,
    (
        select b1.price, b1.provider, b1.bookingUrl from bucket b1
        use keys b.offerIdentifier
        where b1.flightCombinationIdentifier = b.flightCombinationIdentifier
        order by b1.price asc
        limit 1
    ) as offer

from bucket b
where b.flyFrom = 'HAM' and b.flyTo = 'LGW'
group by b.flightCombinationIdentifier
```

Unfortunately it dies with the following error:

```
[
  {
    "code": 4210,
    "msg": "Expression must be a group key or aggregate: (select (`b1`.`price`), (`b1`.`provider`), (`b1`.`bookingUrl`) from `bucket` as `b1` use keys (`b`.`offerIdentifier`) where ((`b1`.`flightCombinationIdentifier`) = (`b`.`flightCombinationIdentifier`)))  order by (`b1`.`price`) limit 1) as `offer`",
    "query_from_user": "select b.flightCombinationIdentifier,\n    (\n        select b1.price, b1.provider, b1.bookingUrl from bucket b1\n        use keys b.offerIdentifier\n        where b1.flightCombinationIdentifier = b.flightCombinationIdentifier\n        order by b1.price asc\n        limit 1\n    ) as offer\n    \nfrom bucket w\nwhere b.flyFrom = 'HAM' and b.flyTo = 'LGW'\ngroup by b.flightCombinationIdentifier"
  }
]
```

What would be the correct approach to get the subquery's result into the result object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT flightCombinationIdentifier, MIN([price, {bookingUrl,price,provider}])[1] AS offer
FROM bucket WHERE flyFrom = 'HAM' AND flyTo = 'LGW'
GROUP BY flightCombinationIdentifier;
```